# Read and split a text file (java)

Tags: java, parsing, file-io, split, readfile

I have some text files with time information, like:

```
46321882696937;46322241663603;358966666
46325844895266;46326074026933;229131667
46417974251902;46418206896898;232644996
46422760835237;46423223321897;462486660
```

For now, I need the third column of the file, to calculate the average.

How can I do this? I need to get every text lines, and then get the last column?

Comment: Okay, so you've got three tasks here: read the file line by line; parse each line; compute the average. How far have you got with each task?

Comment: do you have some code for us?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can read the file line by line using a `BufferedReader` or a `Scanner`, or even some other techinique. Using a Scanner is pretty straightforward, like this:

```
public void read(File file) throws IOException{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

    while(scanner.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    }
}
```

For splitting a String with a defined separator, you can use the split method, that recevies a Regular Expression as argument, and splits a String by all the character sequences that match that expression. In your case it's pretty simple, just the `;`

```
String[] matches = myString.split(";");
```

And if you want to get the last item of an array you can just use it's `length` as parameter. remembering that the last item of an array is always in the index `length - 1`

```
String lastItem = matches[matches.length - 1];
```

And if you join all that together you can get something like this:

```
public void read(File file) throws IOException{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

    while(scanner.hasNext()){
        String[] tokens = scanner.nextLine().split(";");
        String last = tokens[tokens.length - 1];
        System.out.println(last);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can cast the variable last to an Integer with Integer.valueOf(last) and add all the values together.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to read each line of the file and split it by ";" separator and read third element.