# Creating objects by reading txt file

Tags: java, object, streamreader

I am creating a shop simulation. This shop sells: Mobos, CPU, GPU, Disk, RAM, Monitor, Keyaboard, Mouse, Printer...so there is a subclass called Mobo, another called CPU etc. There is also a superclass called Product, because all specific products have some common charecteristics (model, year, manufacturer, price and pieces).
I have a txt file with this structure:

```
ΙΤΕΜ_LIST { 
    ΙΤΕΜ { 
      ΙΤΕΜ_TYPE monitor 
      MODEL LS27F350 
      MODEL_YEAR 2016 
      MANUFACTURER Samsung 
      PRICE 220 
      SCREEN_TYPE LED 
      DIMENSIONS 27 
      RESOLUTION 1920x1080 
      INTERFACES “HDMI Display-Port USB”         
      PIECES 2     
   } 
   ΙΤΕΜ { 
      ΙΤΕΜ_TYPE motherboard 
      MODEL Z370-HD3  
      MODEL_YEAR 2017 
      MANUFACTURER Gigabyte 
      PRICE 80 
      PIECES 4 
      ...          
   } 
   ... 
}
```

What I need to do is to make a program reading a txt file like this above and then create an object. 
So for example, the first object made will be :

```
Product p = new Monitor("LS27F250", 2016, "SAMSUNG"...);
```

The second one will be:

```
Product p = new Motherboard("Z370-HD3", 2017, ...);
```

The thing is that all characteristics, except the ITEM_TYPE obviously, can be in random order into the file (for example: ITEM_TYPE then MANUFACTURER then MODEL).

Any hints on what to do?

For now i have only came up with the basics, making an inputsreamreader and maybe make an array of Strings to store all the tags ( ITEM_LIST, ITEM, ITEM_TYPE, MODEL, ...).

Comment: post your code so we could help you...

Comment: I suggest to use a standalone database like Sqlite or alternate a XML file to store these information... If you want absolutely use a *.txt file with this format you have to write a parser yourself, this is a very custom task, for example visit this page to found hints https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903170/read-and-split-a-text-file-java... As [shahaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5235392/shahaf) already said, post some code...